# How to get the x-height of a font?

Tags: fonts, elisp

`font-info` returns some metrics of a font like the ascent and descent. How to get the x-height?

---

To make sure the question body meets the quality standards of Stack Overflow, here's a randomly generated haiku. I don't think it actually adds anything, but who am I to argue with a heuristic?

```
Oh stack overflow
before common sense ruins
at the perfect ai
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works but 1. it requires `ttfdump` (included in Texlive) and 2. probably doesn't work for all fonts.

```el
(defun my-xheight (font)
  "Return the x-height of FONT."
  (let* ((info (font-info font))
         (file (elt info 12))
         (ascent (elt info 8)))
    (round (* ascent (my-xheight-frac file)))))

(defun my-xheight-frac (file)
  "Return the x-height of a font as a fraction of its ascent height."
  (with-temp-buffer
    (let ((exitcode
           (call-process "ttfdump" nil t nil "-t" "OS/2" file)))
      (unless (= exitcode 0)
        (error (buffer-string))))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (save-match-data
      (let ((sxheight (save-excursion
                        (search-forward-regexp (rx bol (0+ blank) "sxHeight:" (0+ blank)
                                                   (group (1+ digit))))
                        (string-to-number (match-string 1))))
            (ascent (save-excursion
                      (search-forward-regexp (rx bol (0+ blank) "usWinAscent:" (0+ blank)
                                                 (group (1+ digit))))
                      (string-to-number (match-string 1)))))
        (/ sxheight (float ascent))))))
```